# is it possible to add Magento 2 keys after the installation

Tags: magento2, composer

I installed Magento 2 without using composer, because I encountered issues and the hosting company helped me with the installation and did not use composer.

Is it possible to add my private and public key to magento now? So that I could update it using composer from now on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it through system -> web setup wizard

Depending on the version you might get a 200 error, but there is a fix for that here;

[200 Error Fix](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Invalid-response-line-returned-from-server-HTTP-2-200/td-p/113833)

Answer (score 1):

Save auth.json.sample as auth.json

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/auth.json.sample

Put your details in

However it's possible an auth.json have been saved elsewhere under user.

If you are using linux try `whereis auth.json` see what comes up.